# Why does my Hashmap still have duplicates?

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap, duplicates

I hava a hashmap where if I don't find a record to avoid duplicates, I add it to the map.

```
    List<APPPRecord> PFRecord = null;
    while(scroll.next()){
        APPPRecord item = (APPPRecord) scroll.get(0);
        List<ARecord> recs = new ArrayList<ARecord>();
        unique(APPPRecord);
        recs.addAll(APPPRecord);

    HashMap<String, ARecord> uniqueRecs = new HashMap<String, ARecord>();
    for(ARecord records:recs){
        if(!uniqueRecs.containsKey(records.getId())){
            uniqueRecs.put(records.getId(), records);

        }
```

After, I get the values I need out of it.

```
     List<ARecord> finalRecs = new ArrayList<ARecord>();
     finalRecs.addAll(uniqueRecs.values());
```

The problem is I still have duplicates even though my unit test runs fine and only adds unique records. Here's my unit test:

```
    public void testGetUniqueResults(){
    APRecord p1 = new APRecord();
    p1.settId("l1");
    APRecord p2 = new APRecord();
    p2.setId("l2");
    APRecord p3 = new APRecord();
    p3.setId("l1");
    APRecord p4 = new APRecord();
    p4.setId("l4");
    List< APRecord > listPatch = new ArrayList< APRecord >();
    listPatch.add(p1);
    listPatch.add(p2);
    listPatch.add(p3);
    listPatch.add(p4);

    List<ARecord> recs = new ArrayList<ARecord>();
    recs.addAll(listPatch);

    HashMap<String, ARecord> uniqueRecs = new HashMap<String, ARecord>();
    for(ARecord records:recs){
        if(!uniqueRecs.containsKey(records.getId())){
            uniqueRecs.put(records.getId(), records);

        }


    }
    Iterator it = uniqueRecs.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
        System.out.println(pair.getKey()); //outputs l4, l2, l1 as expected

    }

    List<ARecord> finalRecs = new ArrayList<ACCMRecord>(uniqueRecs.values());
    for(ARecord record:finalRecs){
        System.out.println("records final "+record);
    }
```

Why am I still seeing duplicates when I run the actual service code? What would be a fix for that?

EDIT: Hashcode and equals implementation

```
     public class APPPRecord extends AbstratAPRecord implements ARecord{
        private BigInteger autoID;
        private String ACompId = null;
       //setter and getter
      @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if(obj instanceof APPPRecord)
    {
        APPPRecord temp = (APPPRecord) obj;
        if(this.getACompId().equals(temp.getACompId()))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return (this.getACompId().hashCode());        
}}
```

Update: I figured it out. The issue was with another class.

Comment: you may have duplicate records with different ids

Comment: I find same ID duplicates in my result even though my test runs fine.

Comment: I doubt that. a map cannot contain duplicate keys (by definition. If it did, someone would have noticed.) Your keys must be slightly different.

Comment: Why not just define `equals` and `hashCode` for your `ARecord` class, based on the `id`, and use a `HashSet`?

Comment: I strongly suspect your `ARecord` class does not correctly define `equals` and `hashCode`.  Please post your `ARecord` class.

Comment: The test you posted runs fine but your actual code doesn't? I'm sorry, but I don't think we'll be able to help with that - a map can't, by definition, have duplicate keys. You'll need to either debug your code, insert debug print statements or systematically remove parts of your code until you find your issue or you have something of similar length to your test code which you can post here (but the usual issue with hash-based containers is not correctly defining `equals` and `hashCode`, as Louis implied).

Comment: @LouisWasserman Actually, if it's `HashMap<String, ARecord>`, only `String` needs to define those operations (which it does). Since the key is the ID, *perhaps the updating of IDs doesn't correctly remove and reinsert*, but we're really just guessing what the problem is.

Comment: Ah, right.  That said, the OP had a previous question where they really didn't get the distinction between keys and values, so that might still be at work here...?

Comment: updated my question with hash code and equals. @LouisWasserman I actually wanted values out of has map that I implemented. Not sure why there are still duplicates.

Comment: Please read from start since I added some more relevant service code.

Comment: We're still guessing what went wrong.  Please post a test which _fails_ and shouldn't fail.

Comment: The unit test passes and gives me back unique results. When I run the actual code, it runs but my debug statement after the getting the values from hash map still has duplicates.

Comment: @Jay So you have a section of code where you know there are duplicates? So you should be able to write code to populate the map to look **exactly** like that (by just printing out the map at that point and writing code to write those values into it), which produces duplicates (make sure to pay special attention to what the keys are, don't assume they're the ID's of the objects, because that might have changed since you inserted them). If you know how an element is duplicated, you should be able to work backwards to figure out why.